# ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file ...jboss/lib/endorsed/._resolver.jar

Tags: jboss, jar, classnotfoundexception

When starting my JBoss using bin/run.sh I immediately get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file /home/polopoly/jboss/lib/endorsed/._resolver.jar
```

There is indeed a file jboss/lib/endorsed/resolver.jar, but not a ._resolver.jar. Where is the '._' coming from?! I can't find anything like that in the start scripts.

The Jboss is in a Amazon cloud machine and have been scp'd there as a .tgz inside a jar. Could this be a source of error? But I did a "grep -R '._resolver.jar' ." in the jboss dir with no results, so there is no script file with that string.

Comment: Are you using a Mac OS X machine anywhere in your development or deployment processes? I know OS X generates "dot-underscore" prefixed files when building a zip or tar file, or transferring certain files to a non-Mac machine. But I'm not sure why the java app itself would be looking for them. Also, is your resolver.jar a real jar file? Maybe it's a symlink? Try running "jar tvf" on it.

Comment: Yes i use Mac OS X to build the jboss dist. I have found http://codeismandatory.com/?p=42 and http://www.litfuel.net/plush/?postid=147. So you cannot tar on mac and untar on Linux...

Answer (score 1):

After you extracted your MAC tar archive on Linux use something like:

```
find -type f -name '._*' | xargs rm -f
```

on it, and JBoss will stat correctly.